# Yii2: how to define a formatter for GridView columns property

Tags: yii2

I have an `is_active`(tiny-int) field in `user` table.

Also I define some meanings for `is_active`:

code in `params.php`

```
return [
  'enumData' => [
      'is_active' => [1 => '√', 0 => '×'],
  ]
];
```

code in `user\index.php`

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        [
            'attribute' =>   'is_active',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function ($model) {
                return Yii::$app->params['enumData']['is_active'][$model->is_active]

            },
        ],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Want I want is like this in `user\index.php`

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
         'is_active:humanReadable',
    ],
]); ?>
```

I tried to add a helper function, but I was wondered if has a neat way to do that like upon code ?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use [Formatter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.htm) for this?

You can change the output for boolean values by changing [$booleanFormat](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#$booleanFormat-detail) property.

You can do it at runtime through `formatter` component

```
use Yii;

...

Yii::$app->formatter->booleanFormat = ['×', '√'],
```

Or globally with application config:

```
'components' => [
    'formatter' => [
        'class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
        'booleanFormat' => ['×', '√'],
    ],
],
```

Then in `GridView` you can simply write:

```
'is_active:boolean',
```

**Update:**

Multiple values case.

Assuming we have `type` attribute, add this to your model:

```
const self::TYPE_1 = 1;
const self::TYPE_2 = 2;
const self::TYPE_3 = 3;

/**
 * @return array
 */
public static function getTypesList()
{
    return [
        self::TYPE_1 => 'Type 1',
        self::TYPE_2 => 'Type 2',
        self::TYPE_3 => 'Type 3',
    ];
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getTypeLabel()
{
    return self::getTypesList()[$this->type];
}
```

Then in GridView you can output the label like that:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'type',
    'value' => 'typeLabel',
],
```

Comment: But what if the `is_active` have more than 2 value ?

Comment: Normally you should create separate question for that, because initial question was only about boolean values. However I updated the answer with solution for that case.